# Клиент kerio vpn в линукс

Tags: linux, сеть, vpn

Подключается успешно, но на интерфейс kvnet назначается неверный mac адрес. Ответы от сервера приходят на другой мак.

Запрос

```
Ethernet II, Src: e2:75:42:f6:d7:11 (e2:75:42:f6:d7:11), Dst: Microsoft_53:01:00 (44:45:53:53:01:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.253.38.21, Dst: 10.253.38.1
```

ответ

```
Ethernet II, Src: Microsoft_53:01:00 (44:45:53:53:01:00), Dst: 3a:04:ca:08:75:27 (3a:04:ca:08:75:27)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.253.38.1, Dst: 10.253.38.21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем служба не сменила mac (можно найти в `/var/log/kerio-kvc/debug.log`) на интерфейсе `kvnet`.

Выполнить скрипт после того, как соединение установится:

```
#!/bin/bash

mac=$(egrep -io '([0-9a-f]{2}(\-){0,1}){6}' /var/log/kerio-kvc/debug.log | tail -1)

ip link set kvnet addr ${mac//-/:}
```